# curl returns uknown symbols :(

Tags: php, curl

i am doign a curl command which is:

```
     $datapost = curl_init();
$headers = array('Cache-Control: max-age=0', 'RequestVerificationToken: iV2bw0_y6G2IjrjpdbUkXcpaq3iXk3vpr7NbSIWcP6SpIqvepVeabh7QWLGlOwUOE4Io-PqQOHBp7iJQZWW36HCQjt01:6pk0ApHvxxfzlNKC05af2073796HZ7vaMw5pjn2uUhcZYCUBNnC-I0m3-mPo7_9frrfNx8WZbn3abykOlWh25DhglOS9O4mGlHOCEpoCMfxIvMuR0');

curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
ob_start();
return curl_exec ($datapost);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($datapost);
unset($datapost);
```

Which gives me the following:
[Image with the response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f0c6.png), but the result looks like this:
���rו�_���$�"����EJ���

How can i decode this data into a readable text?

Comment: You are asking the server to send you gzip / deflate encoded data so...

Comment: `Accept-encoding: gzip`. if you say you want gzip, you'll get gzip...

Comment: What should i replace? please help me :(

Comment: We just gave you pretty decent pointers. How about following up on it?

Comment: I am using Curl for the first time, it's hard to understand how it is working :(

Comment: I removed Accept gzip, still same error :(

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');  ??

Comment: WOW, THANKS , its my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems,
1: you're returning BEFORE ob_end_clean(), 
try this:

```
ob_start();
$ret=curl_exec ($datapost);
echo ob_get_clean();
return $ret;
```

and 2: you don't set the correct content-type header, so the browser try to render the IMAGE BINARY DATA as TEXT.

for instance, if its a jpg file, do this

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```